# NHibernate C# e SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

Good Morning,

I wonder if there's any method within the NHIBERNATE to which I can retrieve the first row of the table?
For example:

```
Line | ID | Name     |Last Name       |
 1   | 0  | Test     | of Information |
 2   | 1  | Mauricio | Silva          |
```

If I want the first line or the line 1 of the table

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq` to create queries with nHibernate. There is a method called `FirstOrDefault()` which takes only the first record. If the query return empty, the `FirstOrDefault` method will return `null`, so, remember to check the result before using, for sample:

```
var firstItem = session.Query<Entity>().FirstOrDefault();
if (firstItem != null)
{
    string name = firstItem.Name;
    // use object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate does support paging, so we can select "any" record using the `.Take()` and `.Skip()`. In our case we can do it like this:

```
var list = session
    .QueryOver<Person>()
    .Take(1) // this will take just a first record
    //.Skip(0) // we can even skip some, to get next page
    ;
```

Then the resulting `list` will contain 1 or none row...

```
var person = list.FirstOrDefault();
```

Also, we can never be sure, what order will be used by DB engine, so we should use explicit ORDER BY:

```
var list = session
    .QueryOver<Contact>()
    .OrderBy(p => p.ID)
        .Asc
    .Take(1)
     ;
```

Now we can be sure, that the first result will be with ID == 0